# static library has big size

Tags: objective-c, ios, build, static-libraries

I built universal static library with help of this [template](https://github.com/michaeltyson/iOS-Universal-Library-Template)

The problem that is my library libWrapper.a has size 1.3 mb??? :0
while my source code has 130 kb.

**How I can reduce the size of my static lib?**

Other strange thing -

[image]

Each lib has the same size - 1.3 mb. I supposed that universal (fat) libs should have bigger size.

Comment: Did you build your lib in debug or release mode?

Comment: both... And both of them has same size (

Comment: Is the Strip Debug Symbols During Copy flag set to Yes in Release mode?

Comment: yes, it set to YES for release

Comment: So, did you actually build a binary of your app linked with the library, and looked at the size of that?

Comment: Does your library statically link to any other libraries? Remember your binary contains 3 different architectures which means 3x the code including statically linked libraries you may have included in your lib.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Also make sure that you set Generate Debug Symbols to NO in your build settings.  This can reduce the size of your static library by about 30%.

Comment: but it reduced the size by 10% only :(

Comment: Between this and the "Strip Debug Symbols During Copy" set to YES, I got a great 65% reduction in the size of a fat lib.

Answer (score 3):

in terminal run

```
strip -x [youStaticlib.a]
```

Description

```
For dynamic shared libraries, the maximum level of stripping is usually
 -x (to remove all non-global symbols).
```

if you want to know strip other parameter, in terminal run

```
man strip
```

Answer (score -2):

You cant.  Static libraries include all the code that they reference in the form of frameworks inside their executable.

Comment: because they have their linker settings to not include so much, and yes I am sure.

Comment: This is incorrect. Static libraries are simply an archive of .o files. They do *not* include the code from frameworks. Frameworks are dynamically linked.

Comment: Thats what static libraries ARE - hence the name static. Apple does not support static linking to iOS frameworks, but if you are statically linking to 3rd party frameworks all their code will be *statically* linked into your apps executable.

Comment: Also static linking in general is not recommended by Apple for 3rd party or otherwise.

Comment: @user490696 I am curious to know where you read that static linking is not recommended by Apple? How else would people include closed source analytics libraries or even libraries that developers have written themselves?

Comment: I meant static linking to apple frameworks, you can static link to 3rd party libs, obviously.  But theres nothing you can do to reduce the size of your target.

Comment: @user490696 You can't statically link to a dynamic library/framework. Static libraries and dynamic libraries are very different. The former is, as I mentioned before, an archive of .o files the latter is a specially formatted executable.